# Rails: Accessing route segment defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes, defaults

I would like to access the defaults I define for a specific route. But Rails refuses to put it into the *params* hash. Example:

routes.rb:

```
get "packages(/:display)", to: "packages#index", defaults: { display: 'grid' }
```

URL that I call:

```
http://localhost:3000/packages
```

The *params* hash becomes:

```
{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"packages"}
```

But what I would prefer is to get:

```
{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"packages", "display"=>"grid"}
```

The problem is no biggy really. But Rails claims to by DRY so that I thought I could keep the defaults in the *routes.rb* and not repeat them in my controller or view code.

My intention is to display either a grid of results or list of results. And if the user does not specify a certain view I would like to use the grid-style.

(I'm using Rails 4.)

Comment: Do you have an earlier route that `/packages` is matching?

Comment: Oh my. You guessed so right. get "packages" => "packages#index". I commented it out and now the default parameter is passed as expected. Thanks so much for looking into your crystal ball. :)

Comment: Although I get a pretty strange effect now when I call /packages/list. I assumed that *params* is the same as *request.params*. But *params* is {"display"=>"grid", "controller"=>"packages", "action"=>"index"} while *request.params* is {"display"=>"list", "controller"=>"packages", "action"=>"index"}. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested the following route in my Rails 4 app.

```
get "packages(/:display)", to: "packages#index", defaults: { display: "grid" }
```

- `/packages`: `params[:display]` is `"grid"`
- `/packages/list`: `params[:display]` is `"list"`

It's likely you have other routes playing into this still, preventing the same results I lay out above.

Short of finding such conflicts, how about we avoid the optional segment *(the result is the same as above)*?

```
get "packages",          to: "packages#index", display: "grid"
get "packages/:display", to: "packages#index"
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes me think indeed. Seems I'm putting too much effort into URL segments when I should rather use multiple routes to make it more explicit. I will try this. However I'm still confused why *params* and *request.params* give me different results.